# Check if object key is empty

Tags: javascript

I need to check if the object has empty and for this i made:

```js
const params = {
  name: '',
  email: 'john@example.com',
  profession: 'Content Writer',
  age: 29
};
const qs = Object.keys(params).map((key) => key.length && key+"=" + params[key]).join('&');
console.log(qs);
```

I expect:

```js
email=john@example.com&profession=Content Writer&age=29
```

So, the all values which are empty or undefined shouldn't be in the final string.

 Where is the problem in my code?

Comment: You're checking the length of the *key*, not the value…

Answer (score 0):

A simple filter could solve this issue of falsy values in the object.

edit: only consider '' and undefined in the filter predicate

```
const params = {
  name: '',
  email: 'john@example.com',
  profession: 'Content Writer',
  age: 29,
  test1: 0,
  test2: false
};
const qs = Object.keys(params).filter(key => params[key]!== undefined && params[key]!== '' ).map((key) => key+"=" + params[key]).join('&');
console.log(qs);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to discard every key that have empty values, just use a filter to ignore them from your final string:

```js
const params = {
  name: '',
  email: 'john@example.com',
  profession: 'Content Writer',
  age: 29
};

const qs = Object.keys(params)
    .filter(key => {
        return typeof params[key] !== 'undefined' &&
            params[key] !== null &&
            (typeof params[key] !=='string' || (typeof params[key] === 'string' && params[key].length > 0))
    })
    .map((key) => `${key}=${params[key]}`)
    .join('&');
console.log(qs);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let qs = Object.entries(params).map(([key, value]) => {if(value) return `${key}=${value}`}).filter((e)=>e).join('&');
```

You can use `template string` to make one string consisted of literal and variable. And `filter` method returns if the argument is truthy value.

Answer (score 0):

Like [@Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64534390/13331155)'s answer but fixed `0` and `false` filtering out:

```js
const params = {
  name: '',
  email: 'john@example.com',
  profession: 'Content Writer',
  age: 29
};

const qs = Object.keys(params)
    .filter(key => (params[key] !== ''))
    .map((key) => `${key}=${params[key]}`)
    .join('&');
console.log(qs);
```

Comment: It won't filter out keys  that are set to null

Comment: I changed the answer, look above ^

Comment: yes, you set name to null but you get `name=null&email=john@example.com&profession=Content Writer&age=29` with `.filter(key => (params[key] !== ''))`. I don't think it is the expected behavior.

Comment: He just wanted to check if it's empty or not. I don't think that matters as much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Lodash** `_.omitBy(object, [predicate=_.identity])`

> A modern JavaScript utility library delivering modularity, performance & extras.

Docs:

- https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omitBy
- https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isNil

```
var object = {
  name: null,
  email: 'john@example.com',
  profession: 'Content Writer',
  age: 29
};
 
_.omitBy(object, !_.isNil);
// => { email: 'john@example.com', profession: 'Content Writer', age: 29 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **array reduce** method. Traverse the object keys and check if the value is empty(*empty string, null, false or 0*) and if not then add it to the resultant string.

```js
const params = {
  name: '',
  email: 'john@example.com',
  profession: 'Content Writer',
  age: 29,
};
const qs = Object.keys(params)
  .reduce((p, c) => {
    let str = p;
    if (params[c]) {
      str += `&${c}=${params[c]}`;
    }
    return str;
  }, '')
  .slice(1);
console.log(qs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [URLsearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to automatically handle URL encoding

```js
const params = {
  name: '',
  email: 'john@example.com',
  profession: 'Content Writer',
  age: 29
};
const sp = new URLSearchParams()
Object.keys(params).forEach((key) => { if (params[key]) sp.set(key,params[key]) })
console.log(sp.toString())
```